# Problem installing Clonezilla from desktop repos on Ubuntu and Kali Linux

Tags: software-installation, kali

I am trying to **install Clonezilla** on my Raspberry Pi 2 running Kali Linux v1.1.0 by following a [tutorial](https://wi-phye.com/featured/how-to-setup-clonezilla-on-linux-ubuntu-quick-start-guide/) for the desktop version :

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

then I add:

```
deb http://free.nchc.org.tw/drbl-core drbl stable
```

And when I try to install:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install clonezilla
W: Failed to fetch http://free.nchc.org.tw/drbl-core/dists/drbl/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'stable/binary-armhf/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

This procedure works OK on a Kali Linux v1.1.0 desktop version.

I am not very experienced on Raspberry: is it possible to install some program like Clonezilla **from a standard repository**? Or should the repository be Raspberry Pi specific?

NOTE-01: Tested on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS for Raspberry Pi 2, and the error message is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the repository must be specific to the [CPU architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_instruction_set_architectures#Instruction_sets)  you are using. Raspberry Pi Is not a x86.